# Archetypes and Schemata() method

Tags: plone, archetypes

I am customizing Plone Archetypes content type by overriding Schemata() method to have vocabulary contents dynamically:

```
def Schemata(self):
    """ Overrides field definitions in fly.

    """        

    # XXX: Cache this method?

    schemata = getSchemata(self).copy()
    settings = self.getResearchSettings()

    for row in settings.getFieldCustomizations():
        name = row.get("fieldName", None)
        vocab = row.get("vocabToUse", None)

        field = schemata.get(name, None)
        if field and vocab:
            # Modify field copy ion 
            field.vocabulery = vocab

    return schemata
```

Do I need to use cache decorator for Schemata() function or is Archetypes handling Schemata() internally so smart so that it calls it only once per request?

Plone 4.0.

Comment: Why not insert a simple logging.getLogger(__name__).info('Calling self.Schemata() for updating customisations')? Then you'd know! :-)

Comment: Also, WTF? You are altering global field instances on the fly, don't do that!

Answer (score 2):

forgot Schemata... you should not touch that stuff.

you can have dynamic vocabularies using object methods or zope vocabularies.

[first hit on google](http://www.universalwebservices.net/web-programming-resources/zope-plone/dynamic-vocabularies-in-plone-archetypes)

Comment: Yep. But the trick here is that we need to retrofit vocabularies by field name to Archetypes. You configure pair of field name -> linesfield in the site settings. AT dynamic vocabulary method does not pass the field name to object method, so it is no go.

Comment: @mikko-ohtamaa: Why not creating one vocabulary per field ?

Comment: The site admin is free to mix and match different vocabularies with different fields. E.g. he can assign the same "Units and departments" vocab for field "Units" or field "Departments" depending on the organization structure :(

Comment: I see. Maybe you can define your own field (or set of fields) that overrides the 'Vocabulary' method (Products.Archetypes.Field#L412) of the field and call the zope vocab as you like it?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to cache the results of Schema() and Schemata(), as at least Schema() is called multiple times during the same request.